# Graphics card replacement for a 6 year old pc

Tags: graphics-cards

I bought my pc six years ago and now want to replace my graphcis card.

I'd like to play the upcoming games like Starfield and maybe The Elders Scrolls 6 with this new card. I'm looking for a product that costs around 300 euros and is compatible with the other pieces of my computer.

Here is my computer spec:

**Graphics card :** AMD Radeon 7850 HD 2 Go

**Screen resolution:** 1920 x 1080

**Motherboard :** ASUS H97M-E

**Power supply:** Antec Basiq 500 Watts

**Processor:** Intel i5 4690 3.5 GHz

**RAM :** 2 x 4 Go DDR3

**Operating system :** Windows 10

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at the following graphics cards and decide which one is the best suited for you:

- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 (6G)
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

Or if you are an AMD kinda' person:

- AMD Radeon RX 570
- AMD Radeon RX 580

These are what I would recommend. Considering your i5 has only 4 cores and 4 threads, you won't get a lot of performance, there might even be a slight bottleneck if you opt for a higher end card from the list. I would however do just that, as if you later decide to upgrade the CPU & other parts when needed, you won't have to buy a new GPU again, these will be "decent" for 3-5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused. Go for

> NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti

This would be best GPU for your configuration at $270